# How to wait for one task to finish before in java?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a string and I am parsing it and storing it to JsonArray and then iterating over it. There is a race condition that my parser isn't completing and the control moves ahead. I want this to complete first then move ahead.

I tried to wait and notify. It isn't working.

```
Response res = run(el);
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonTree = parser.parse(res.body().string());

try {
    wait();
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("jsontree  :  "+ jsonTree);

JsonArray array=jsonTree.getAsJsonArray();

notifyAll();
if(jsonTree.isJsonArray()) {
     System.out.println("I am JSONARRAY");
}

for(JsonElement element: array) {
     count++;
     System.out.println("count   "+ count);
}
```

Right now jsonTree is empty and it looks like this: `[]`. I want the jsonTree to have objects. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide the necessary classes to compile this? In the usual case where you want to wait for a thread to finish you would use the Thread.join() method.

Comment: `JsonParser.parse` is a blocking call, so there wouldn’t be a race condition. Are you sure that `res.body()` is actually returning a non-empty json?

Answer (score 0):

Java by default is executed line by line i.e its synchronous in nature by default. It means once your parser will complete then only it will move to next line. You wont require any asynchronous way to implement it. Just check for correctness of your response obj and parser.